# Row_Number, Rank, Dense_rank all starts at random numbers for dataset groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table that contains product data with quote information (estimation given to a customer given by a sales rep on particular products) for specific accounts. It also has financial quarter and financial week corresponding to the date it was created. There can be multiple quotes for the same product and the same account depending on back and forth communication between the sales rep and the customer. I want to rank these quotes based on account and product combination and order it by the quote that has been created the last. Below is the query I am using:

Please note I have also tried using Rank and Dense_Rank instead of row_number

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT 
     Account_ID
    ,Quote_Number
    ,Product
    ,Fiscal_Quarter
    ,Fiscal_Week
    ,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY Account_ID, Product ORDER BY 
QUOTE_CREATE_DATE DESC, QTE_NUM_VAL DESC) AS ROWNUM
FROM 
tbl_Quotes_Data 
WHERE 
Fiscal_Quarter IN ('2018-Q4')
) X
```

However, when I run this query it works fine for some accounts while for a majority of accounts the row number gets captured incorrectly and I am not able to figure out why. I see row number starting only from 600 for some accounts while for other accounts it even starts from 10,000. As the next step involves considering row numbers that are ranked as 1, this creates an issue. Would be very grateful if someone could help me understand the reason for this behaviour of the code.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide the table design and sample data.

Comment: Are you sure the order of the result set is not fooling you? If you order the data the same as the row_number() function , Account_Id, Product, QUOTE_CREATE_DATE DESC, QTE_NUM_VAL DESC, then you should see all your data as expected.

Comment: Until we can get some data for testing, you probably need to add `ORDER BY` `Account_ID, Product, ROWNUM` on the outer query if you expect the data to be returned in any specified order. I don't think you need `QTE_NUM_VAL DESC` in the window function either.

Comment: Maybe you have some additional conditions (or INNER JOINs) outside the derived table X (that you have omitted here).

Answer (score 1):

Depend on the number of rows obtained, it is possible that the ordering is causing the issue. 
I would propose you to rewrite it in a clearer way using CTE and filtering in the inside query:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
    Account_ID,
    Quote_Number,
    Product,
    Fiscal_Quarter,
    Fiscal_Week,
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY Account_ID, Product 
                  ORDER BY QUOTE_CREATE_DATE DESC, QTE_NUM_VAL DESC) AS ROWNUM
FROM tbl_Quotes_Data 
WHERE Fiscal_Quarter IN ('2018-Q4')
) 
SELECT *
FROM CTE
ORDER BY Account_ID, Product, ROWNUM;
```